# Getting the SUM of grouped numeric field as hh:mm in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a field of type numeric(15,5) that represents time that I need to group and SUM in a LINQ to SQL statement

In SQL I have worked out that the following query will convert the value to minutes and sum it, from which I can then apply further calculations on the data to convert it to hh:mm

```
SELECT 
    StaffID,
    sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00',  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SECOND, HrsWorked * 3600, 0),108) AS TIME)) )
from dbo.StaffHours
Group by StaffID
```

But am unable to represent this in LINQ. Is it possible or is there an easier way to do it?

For clarity, I am working with 3rd party data and unable to get definitive answer on how the data is being captured, but am working under the assumption that a value of 5.83300 equates to 349 minutes based on the conversion above

Comment: how does hrsWorked represent time - is it the time in hours eg 1.5 = 1h30m? Did you try to just group/sum in linq then just format the resulting seconds e.g. using a TimeSpan?

Comment: I am working with 3rd party data and so having to make some assumptions, but an example value is 5.83300 which I am treating as being 349 minutes based on the conversion above which is 6:21:36 in hh:mm:ss

Comment: 5.833 hours is 349 minuts is 05:49:00 in hh:mm:ss or am I missing something

Comment: Sorry, yes, my mistake. you are correct,

Comment: Is it really LINQ to SQL? What database engine?

Comment: I get that 5.833 hours is actually 350 minutes (rounded) or `5:49:59` in h:mm:ss rounded. That seems like a really, really long way around saying `HrsWorked * 60`.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflowSandbox
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var staffHours = GetStaffHours().ToArray();

            // Using extensions

            var totalViaExtensions = staffHours
                .GroupBy(x => x.StaffID, (StaffId, lines) => new
                {
                    StaffId,
                    TotalTime = lines
                        .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, line) => sum + TimeSpan.FromHours(line.HrsWorked))
                        .TotalMinutes
                });

            // Using C# LINQ

            var totalViaLINQ = from x in staffHours
                group x by x.StaffID
                into staffMember
                select new
                {
                    StaffId = staffMember.Key, TotalTime = staffMember
                        .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, line) => sum + TimeSpan.FromHours(line.HrsWorked))
                        .TotalMinutes
                };

        }

        public static IEnumerable<StaffHours> GetStaffHours()
        {
            // Placeholder
            return Enumerable.Empty<StaffHours>();
        }
    }

    public class StaffHours
    {
        public int StaffID { get; set; }
        public double HrsWorked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julius. I have the following simplified code:
   return (from ad in _repo.StaffHours
  group new { s } by new { s.StaffID } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        StaffID= g.Key.StaffID,
                        MinutesWorked= g.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, line) => sum + TimeSpan.FromHours((double)line.s.HrsWorked.Value)).TotalMinutes,
                    })

Which is giving me the error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Aggregate[<>f__AnonymousType37`2,TimeSpan]

Comment: As far as I know, `Aggregate` is not supported by LINQ to databases.